# How to activate accordion header using element ID?

Tags: jquery, html, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

I am having issues trying to activate a header based on ID and not by the actual element.  Can anyone please help me... This is what I have right now..

```
$(function() {
  $( "#accordion" ).accordion({ collapsible: true, active: false, 
        animate:50, header: "#cat" });    
});

<div id="accordion">
    <div id="cat">Pizza </div>

    <div> Regular Cheese Pizza </div>
    <div> Regular Cheese Pizza </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I figured out the issue. I needed to wrap all my content around one div child element like so

```
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({ collapsible: true, active: false, animate:50, header: "#cat" });

        });





    </script>
</head>
<body>




<div id="accordion">
<div id='cat'>Pizza </div>

<div>

<div>Pizza</div>
<div>Pepperoni Pizza</div>

</div>



</div>
```